# file names in rotating order

Tags: linux, shell, ls

I am working on a music player using mpc function and I want to implement a "next-folder" function. I need to change the order of ls output in this manner...

If I have this files in a directory...

```
folder
  |_file 1
  |_file 2
  |_file 3
  |_file 4
  |_file 5
```

I want a function that returns me the file names, the first time I run it, in this order:

```
folder
  |_file 1
  |_file 2
  |_file 3
  |_file 4
  |_file 5
```

The next time, in this order

```
folder
  |_file 2
  |_file 3
  |_file 4
  |_file 5
  |_file 1
```

The next time, in this order

```
folder
  |_file 3
  |_file 4
  |_file 5
  |_file 1
  |_file 2
```

The next time, in this order

```
folder
  |_file 4
  |_file 5
  |_file 1
  |_file 2
  |_file 3
```

I.e. each time I run the function, I need the first file of the last run in the last position...

Comment: Have you actually tried anything?

Comment: Why on earth do you need this

Comment: I'm sorry, It's edited now. I had an error...

Comment: Why do you do me a negative point?? I need help...

Comment: Provide your code and describe what it does wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why your music player needs to rely on [ls](/questions/tagged/ls), but you can try something like this

```sh
#!/bin/bash
print() {
  [[ $1 -eq 0 ]] && ls -1 && exit 0

  ls | tail -n "+$(($1+1))"
  ls | head -n $1
}

[[ $1 =~ ^[0-9]+$ ]] || { echo "Usage: $0 [0-9]+" && exit 1; }

num_files=$(ls | wc -l)
print $(($1 % $num_files))
```

Example

```
> ls
file\ 1  file\ 2  file\ 3  file\ 4  file\ 5
> ./.abovescript 0
file 1
file 2
file 3
file 4
file 5
> ./.abovescript 1
file 2
file 3
file 4
file 5
file 1
> ./.abovescript 2
file 3
file 4
file 5
file 1
file 2
...
```

And you can wrap that in something that saves the previous state, if you want it to change every time.